# Update WPF ListBoxItem without ListBox.Items.Refresh()?

Tags: wpf, listbox, refresh, listboxitem

I have a `DataTemplate` that I use to display details from a class in a `ListBox`. The `DataTemplate` has an `EventTrigger` attached to the item's `Loaded` event that uses a `DoubleAnimation` to fade each item into view as they are added to the `ObservableCollection` that is bound to the `ListBox`.  It also has a `DataTrigger` that uses a `DoubleAnimation` and a `ColorAnimation` (`RepeatBehavior="Forever"`) to animate a glow effect under a certain condition. So far, so good.

The application requires that the item properties need to be updated every few seconds. The problem comes after updating a property of an item in the `ListBox`, when calling `ListBox.Items.Refresh()`. This resets the animations, so that each item fades into view and the glow effect restarts every few seconds. The item property values don't update if I don't call `Refresh`. My question is, is there a way to refresh each item individually or get around this problem somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the individual items in your `ObservableCollection<T>` implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).  As long as they do, the bindings should update automatically, without requiring an explicit refresh.

Comment: Ah sorry Reed, I just answered myself before I saw your answer. I'll give you credit anyway. :)